# Save Gmail Attachments on Google drive - unknown file type

Tags: google-apps-script

I looked for previous questions on this subject and found some posts from a few years ago. They don't exactly match my problem and when I try them I get more run errors than the script I am using.  In my case, my script creates the files but they show up in my google drive as "unknown file" and can't be opened or previewed in Google drive.  However, if I download the file to my pc, it opens and previews correctly and without any problem.  How do I correct the "unknown" designation in my Google Drive?
I've tried a lot of possible solutions but either they get run time errors or I end up with an "empty" file.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening or how to correct the unknown files attribute?

```
//pasted by Cooper as an example
function  putyourcodehere() {
  //this was posted via a ctrl-K
}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: I@cooper... would post the code if I could but I've tried everything...   4 spaces, CTRL-K, code snipped copied and pasted , block quotes - nothing works!!

Comment: ctrl-k worked for me in your post

Answer (score 0):

#### Save Attachment to a folder

```
function lfunko() {
  const query = 'subject:ThisIsATestMessage';
  Gmail.Users.Messages.list(gobj.globals.calendarid, { q: query }).messages.forEach(m => {
    GmailApp.getMessageById(m.id).getAttachments().forEach(a => {
      DriveApp.getFolderById(gobj.globals.testfolderid).createFile(a.copyBlob()).setName(a.getName());
    })
  })
}
```

gobj.globals is an object of global variables I use so that I don't have to redact them when used within answers that will be posted on SO.  Just treat them as things you will have to replace with your own local variables.  I used gobj.globals.calendarid because that's my email address which is what they want for the userid

Of course you will have to enable the Gmail API

Comment: I tried this and got no errors but I can't find my attachment files anywhere.  What does gobj.globals.testfolderid  refer to?  I tried googling the entire phrase or just gobj.globals and found nothing

Comment: What did you use for the search and did you change the folder id?

Comment: I used my own search criteria that have been working for me.  How do I change the folder id - I didn't see any variable that defined it so I figured it was some sort of constant like basefolder...

Comment: gobj.globals.testforlderid is a global variable for me.  For you it's undefined.  A SO assumption is that were both programmers and we both have some knowledge of Javascript and developer tools.

Comment: I come from the business world - database programming, sql, vb - for past 20 or so years - javascript is new to me(and very strange), so it google script - every language has its own way of defining global variables - so now I trying to find how to do that here

Comment: And trying a line at beginning of script  testfolderid = "testApr22" did nothing - folder is still empty

Comment: I will pick this up again tomorrow.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: testApr22 does not look like a folder id to me

Comment: I've done some more testing...

Comment: //pasted by Cooper as an example
function  putyourcodehere() {
  //this was posted via a ctrl-K
}

Comment: Here is my code {
  //this was posted via a ctrl-K
}

Comment: That didn't work either - I'm getting nowhere trying to paste my code which is making this post next to useless.

Comment: That didn't work either - I'm getting nowhere trying to paste my code which is making this post next to useless.  I tried a number of tests.  The attachment I'm trying to save is a pdf file(1.mb).  If I use your example with get data as string, my saved file is a pdf but is only 122 bytes and can't be previewed.  If I change the get data as string to copy blob, I get a file that is 15 bytes long which says it is a pdf but opens with google docs and contains the words "Gmail Attachment".   My original code creates a 1mb file that is unknown and won't open unless downloaded.

Comment: Basically all I can do is say thanks for your time and help.  That ctrl-k for posting code is a shocker.   I've never seen any forum or board where I had this kind of problem.  I guess I'll have to look elsewhere for help.  Thanks again for trying to help me.

Comment: I tried it with a PDF using the Gmail API and it works fine.  You did not specify the file type and the other version worked fine for me but this version also works for pdfs rather nicely

Comment: I hope this latest solution works better for you.

Comment: Nope, still does not work.  So taking another approach, tried test emails with .doc, .txt, .png files etc - all worked fine.  Tried a regular, non-emailed, pdf file - worked ok.  So has to be something with the pdf formatting used by this scanner/multifunction printer.   Since I can't replace the device, I decided that google script will not work - need to look at other alternatives.  Thank you for your help - I learned quite a bit and might be able to use that in the future with another project.  Much appreciated!!!